# python passing argument containing quote

Tags: python, function, arguments

I'm learning to scrape text from the web. Ive written the following function

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def get_url(source_url):
    r  = requests.get(source_url)
    data = r.text
    #extract HTML for parsing
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
    #get H3 tags with class ...
    h3list = soup.findAll("h3", { "class" : "entry-title td-module-title" })
    #create data structure to store links in
    ulist = []
    #pull links from each article heading
    for href in h3list:
        ulist.append(href.a['href'])
    return ulist
```

I am calling this from a separate file...

```
from print1 import get_url 

ulist = get_url("http://www.startupsmart.com.au/")

print(ulist[3])
```

The problem is that the css selector I am using is quite unique to the site I am parsing. So the function is a bit 'brittle'. I want to pass the css selector as an argument to the function

If I add a parameter to the function definition

```
def get_url(source_url, css_tag):
```

and try to pass `"h3", { "class" : "entry-title td-module-title" }`

it spazzes out

> TypeError: get_url() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

I tried escaping all the quotes but it still doesn't work.

I'd really appreciate some help. I can't find a previoud answer to this one.

Comment: Are you sured you defined `def get_url(source_url, css_tag):` correctly and after doing that again imported the changed function? Looks like your function defination change was not reflected in the file where you are calling `get_url()`

Comment: Your error is not about the quotes, its about the `get_url()` function that, as stated, takes only (exactly) one argument.

Comment: I think this problem you identified is correct. I needed to restart my python for it to recognise thesecond arguament after I added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a version that works:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def get_url(source_url, tag_name, attrs):
    r = requests.get(source_url)
    data = r.text
    # extract HTML for parsing
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
    # get H3 tags with class ...
    h3list = soup.findAll(tag_name, attrs)
    # create data structure to store links in
    ulist = []
    # pull links from each article heading
    for href in h3list:
        ulist.append(href.a['href'])
    return ulist

ulist = get_url("http://www.startupsmart.com.au/", "h3", {"class": "entry-title td-module-title"})

print(ulist[3])
```

Comment: This works. I don't really understand why but thank you

Comment: @AxleMax what don't you understand about it? You seem to think that you can combine multiple values into one by putting quotes around, but it doesn't work like that at all. So I just passed separate values.